# Deserializing Enum, which contains Map

Tags: java, rest, enums, jackson, deserialization

my enum:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)
public enum Currency {

    USD("USD", "United States Dollar"),
    EUR("EUR", "Euro"),
    BGP("BGP", "British Pound"),
    AUD("AUD", "Australian Dollar"),
    CAD("CAD", "Canadian Dollar");

    private final String shortName;
    private final String fullName;
    private Map<Enum, Double> rates;

    Currency(String shortName, String fullName) {
        this.shortName = shortName;
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.rates = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public String getShortName() {
        return shortName;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public Map<Enum, Double> getRates() {
        return rates;
    }

}
```

Postman response I get from another rest api:

```
{
"shortName": "EUR",
"fullName": "Euro",
"rates": {
    "AUD": 1.62,
    "CAD": 1.47,
    "USD": 1.11,
    "BGP": 0.86,
    "EUR": 1.0
}
```

}

Title pretty much sums up what I need. Any ideas how to serialize the postman response in my code, so i have enum as a result, which contains all properties, including "rates" map?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a `static` factory method annotated with `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator` annotation. In case when whole `JSON Object` represents `enum`, `Jackson` automatically converts it to `Map`, so this method should have signature like below:

```
@JsonCreator
public static Currency from(Map<String, Object> value)
```

Below showcase provides complete implementation:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./src/main/resources/test.json");

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        Currency currency = mapper.readValue(jsonFile, Currency.class);
        System.out.println(currency + " => " + currency.getRates());
    }
}

@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)
enum Currency {

    USD("USD", "United States Dollar"),
    EUR("EUR", "Euro"),
    BGP("BGP", "British Pound"),
    AUD("AUD", "Australian Dollar"),
    CAD("CAD", "Canadian Dollar");

    private final String shortName;
    private final String fullName;
    private Map<Enum, Double> rates;

    Currency(String shortName, String fullName) {
        this.shortName = shortName;
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.rates = Collections.emptyMap();
    }

    public String getShortName() {
        return shortName;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public Map<Enum, Double> getRates() {
        return rates;
    }

    public static Currency fromShortName(String value) {
        for (Currency currency : values()) {
            if (currency.getShortName().equals(value)) {
                return currency;
            }
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException(value + " is not found!");
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public static Currency from(Map<String, Object> value) {
        String shortName = value.getOrDefault("shortName", "").toString();
        Currency currency = fromShortName(shortName);

        Map<String, Double> rates = (Map<String, Double>) value.getOrDefault("rates", Collections.emptyMap());
        Map<Enum, Double> newRates = new HashMap<>(9);
        rates.forEach((k, v) -> {
            newRates.put(Currency.fromShortName(k), v);
        });

        currency.rates = Collections.unmodifiableMap(newRates);
        return currency;
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
EUR => {EUR=1.0, AUD=1.62, CAD=1.47, USD=1.11, BGP=0.86}
```

### Warning

`enum` should be an [Immutable object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) and keeping rates `Map` inside is not a good idea. You should definitely try to remove it from `enum`. In multi thread environment you need to guarantee that this `Map` will not be change during the read. So, in implementation I do not change already used `Map` but create new every time.